# error when running real time script with python

Tags: python

i have a file.log from syslog server and i want to parse the file based on columns and put into different file (parsing.log)
when i run my script there is an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "coding/parsing.py", line 17, in <module>
    for line in loglines:
  File "coding/parsing.py", line 7, in follow
    time.sleep(0.1)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

below is my script :

```
import time
def follow(thefile):
    thefile.seek(0,2)
    while True:
        line = thefile.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue
        yield line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logfile = open("file.log","r")
    logout = open("/parsing.log","w")
    loglines = follow(logfile)
    category={'malware','phishing'}
    severity={'low','medium','critical'}
    for line in loglines:
            col = line.split(",")
        if len(col) >1 and col[33] in category or col[34] in severity:
            logout.write(col[1]+","+col[2]+","+col[3]+","+col[4]+"\n")

        else:
            pass
```

how to handle it?

Comment: The `KeyboardInterrupt` exception is usually thrown because you pressed `CTRL-C` in the terminal where you run your program.

Comment: line 8, try `break` instead of `continue`